# When use View instead of ScrollView it shows an empty screen

Tags: css, react-native, view, react-native-scrollview

I do not want the header view to scroll and only need the body of the screen to scroll.

I have 2 screens.
1. Names.js 2. StudentsList.js

The content inside the Names.js is same as StudentsList.js. So I have used the Names.js as a component in StudentsList.js

Eg)Names.js

```
<View>
  <Header/>
 <keyboardAwareScrollView>
 </keyboardAwareScrollView>
</View>
```

Eg) StudentsList.js

```
 <View>
    {
      <View> 
      <Names>
      </Names>
      </View> 
     }
    </View>
```

Here the Names.js is working fine. But the StudentsList.js not shows the body of the screen and it only shows the Header section. Also If I change the View as ScrollView in StudentsList.js I can able to see the screen but the Header is scrolling

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for this and Added flex:1 for the view